# How to fix no matching overloading function found?

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to write in C++ the function similar to range in python, taking various types of numerical arguments and returning vector of user-specified type. Do not understand the origin of error.

If step_value just set to typename T which is same as type of returning vector, everything works fine. But if typename of output vector and step_value are different, I keep receiving error described below

```
template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
vector <T> range(T1 end_value, T2 begin_value = 0, T3 step_value = 1)
{
    vector <T> output_value(0);
    T converted_begin_value = static_cast<T>(begin_value);
    T converted_end_value = static_cast<T>(end_value);
    T converted_step_value = static_cast<T>(step_value);
    if (converted_step_value > 0)
    {
        if (converted_begin_value <= converted_end_value)
        {
            T current_value = converted_begin_value;
            while (current_value <= converted_end_value)
            {
                output_value.push_back(current_value);
                current_value += converted_step_value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (converted_step_value < 0)
    {
        if (converted_begin_value >= converted_end_value)
        {
            T current_value = converted_begin_value;
            while (current_value >= converted_end_value)
            {
                output_value.push_back(current_value);
                current_value += converted_step_value;
            }
        }
    }
    return output_value;
}`

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
        vector <double> test = range(10,6,2);
        vector <int> test2 = range(10,6,2);
}
```

Both lines in the main function give same errors
Error   C2672    'range': no matching overloaded function found
Error   C2783    'std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> range(T1,T2,T3)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Comment: C++ cannot deduce by return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what the error you were getting is, but it worked for me by adding the type of the template return value. Other than that I got no errors and it all worked right away.

See if changing your main like this works:

```
int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
        vector <double> test = range <double> (10,6,2);
        vector <int> test2 = range <int> (10,6,2);
}
```

Edit from comment:
`C++ cannot deduce by return type`
explains why this would work :+1:

Comment: _I'm not totally sure what the error you were getting is_ See panta reis comment... ;-)